# Integrate applet in html?

Tags: java, html, applet, classnotfoundexception

```
<html>
<applet code="de.wim.outldd.examples.DragDropTest_ModeMemoryStream" archive="outIdd.jar" width="500" height="500"/>

</html>
```

I try to open this [applet](http://www.wilutions.com/outldd/download.html) in HTML, but I get a ClassNotFoundException. The html is in the same directory as the .jar. In the code atribute I put the directory structure to the class in the .jar. Somebody please try these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<applet 
  code="de.wim.outldd.examples.DragDropTest_ModeMemoryStream" 
  archive="outIdd.jar" 
  width="500" 
  height="500"/>
```

The applet element was ever intended to be self-closed, and that is a lower case 'l' (for Lucy) rather than an upper case 'I' (for Imogen) in the jar name.  So the element should be something like:

```
<applet 
  code="de.wim.outldd.examples.DragDropTest_ModeMemoryStream" 
  archive="outldd.jar" 
  width="500" 
  height="500">
</applet>
```

Comment: Thanks so much would have figured that one myself, though no I get a java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError??